# Grails - How to send a personInstance ID from gsp to domain class?

Tags: sql, grails

I'm a complete newbie in grails and I need you guys' help.
I have my sql query in the domain class. I put [1] to see the result but ultimately I'd like to send an argument in that place to display the result according to the person's id number.

```
def dataSource

def someMethod() {

    def sql = new Sql(dataSource)

    def resultRows = sql.rows('select * from result where id = ?', [1])
}
```

And this is what I have in my gsp.

```
<g:each in="${personInstance.someMethod()}" status="i" var="results">
    <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
        <td>${results.column_1}</td>
        <td>${results.column_2}</td>
        <td>${results.column_3}</td>
    </tr>
</g:each>
```

How do I send a parameter from view to domain class? 
Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think the data is flowing the wrong way. The controller should be providing the view with the data, the view should not be looking up the data. If the controller doesn't have your ID yet (if it's derived from user input) a view should exist that uses a form to submit the data to the controller, and then the controller can provide this view.

Comment: So how should I do this? Should I put the method in the controller?
Then how do I view it in a table?

Comment: Have the action (method in controller) return the necessary data based on passed in parameters.

Comment: That's is my issue. I cannot figure out the syntax for passing in parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see how Grails 'would like' your controller and view code to look, try letting Grails generate the code for you.  Even if you don't keep that code in your final project, it is still useful as an instructional tool.

```
arc$ grails create-app Tester1
arc$ cd Tester1
arc$ grails
grails> create-domain-class Person
-- add some attributes to your Person domain class, save the file
grails> generate-all tester1.Person
```

Now go look at the PersonController.groovy, and the various views. Basically, it's marshal your data in the controller, pass it to the views, views operate on what they're given.

Very basic example of passing arbitrary data to the gsp:

```
// show method for an Adventure
def show(Adventure adventure) {
    // a String to pass to the gsp
    def attribute = 'Bilbo'
    // an Array to pass to the gsp
    def attributeList = ['Dwalin','Balin','etc']
    // create a map of values that are 'automagically' passed
    // to the show.gsp
    [adventure: adventure, hobbit: attribute, dwarves: attributeList]
}
```

The adventure, hobbit, and dwarves variables are all available in the gsp. The template code likes to use verbose naming, like adventureInstance, but as long as your gsp code uses the keynames in the map you define, you're good to go.

Comment: I did that. It confused me a lot with many of those somethingInstance and vars... My issue is I can't figure out the syntax for passing in the parameters.

Comment: Hmm..., my two cents would say that you should get the data marshaling code out of the gsp and into the controller (move that personInstance.someMethod() code). In some camps. the belief is that models have business logic, controllers marshal data given inputs (params), and views just present. So in the controller method, get the data from that someMethod() call, and pass it to the view.

Comment: Yes! I solved the problem. Thank you danehammer, tylerwal, and railsdog. 
I did put my logic in the controller and used the result map to view it in the GSP.